# In springboot application how to get rid of the AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT in the logs

Tags: logging, spring-boot

In my springboot application I get the below log generated when using orbitz consul client along with spring-consul. This log gets generated when executing a period task which uses orbitz's consul client at a frequency of 2 mins. I want to turn off the below logs as they unnecessarily populate the log files.

```
AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer [pool-45-thread-1] [DEBUG] [] 


=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

    ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration matched
    ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesBeans matched
    ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesBeans matched

Negative matches:
-----------------

   ConsulAutoConfiguration.RetryConfiguration did not match
   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.RsaEncryptionConfiguration did not match
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor (OnClassCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.VanillaEncryptionConfiguration did not match
      - @ConditionalOnMissing classes not found: org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor (OnClassCondition)
      - Keystore nor key found in Environment (EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.KeyCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None
```

Comment: Something's enabled debug logging, either for a specific package or by launching with `--debug`. It's impossible to say what that is as you haven't provided any information about how your app is being launched or how it's configured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add logging configuration for this particular package, f.e. if you are using Logback:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging">
    <level value="INFO"/>
  </logger>
```

Because current logging happens at level DEBUG.

Comment: adding info level logging makes sense. Also I saw that in latest version of spring boot they disabled debug level logging which helped to solve this problem even without the logger changes.